# Ошибка с AndEngine

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, у меня проблема с движком AndEngine, когда я запускаю приложение оно сразу выдает ошибку

Comment: сегодня выходной у экстрасенсов... =(

Comment: Перезагружать пробовали?

Comment: Дело не в коде. Я пробовал с несколькими примерами из интернета все равно оно сразу при запуске вылетает

Comment: и в консоль не каких логов не падает?

Comment: В консоль выводит  FATAL EXCEPTION: main и еще 20 ошибок

Comment: переустановите СДК, хотя лог всё равно хотелось бы глянуть

Answer (score 1):

Как у вас в манифесте активити обозначена?
должна быть типа

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
```

когда измените перестройте проект и запустите

для отображения лога рекомендую пользоваться сервисами типа pastebin.com

Comment: Аctivity обозначена вот так 

`<activity android:name=".QwActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>`

Answer (score 1):

Покажите полный код вашего манифеста, или проверьте сами, чтобы в нем был правильно указан

```
package="com.my.qw"
```

Проверьте, что у вас файл создан в соответствующем package, что называется он правильно.